# Is it bad to use MacBook pro with battery every day.

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Is it bad to use new MacBook Pro with battery every day? Or would it be better for the battery lifetime to use battery only one day a week?

The problem is that I don't think I can change battery if it gets bad...it's built into the MacBook I think.

Answer (score 4):

There is no harm in running on battery most of the time.

To get the most out of your MacBook Pro's battery, follow the [Notebook Battery advice from Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html): unplug and use your battery until empty about once a month, then charge back up to full.

If you need help following Apple's advice, use [Battery Guardian](http://www.dssw.co.uk/batteryguardian/); it is free and will remind you when to deplete your battery.